# How to align the object on every page to the bottom for multiple pages in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, workflow, alignment, actions

What would be the best approach to perform a simple action that needs to be repeated in 800+ pages. Here is what each of my page looks like. All I need to do in each page is align the object to the bottom of the page.

[image: align object to bottom across multiple pages indesign]

I tried `Transform again` but it didn't help. Also, I couldn't find an action tab or a script that would do this in InDesign. Even if I do this manually, there is a chance with my job that I'll get this kind of work often, so it would be great if anyone could suggest a smarter method of doing this.

**How can I quickly align the object on each page of a document to the bottom?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In situations like these, the quickest way is usually to use a script. (At least if your 800 pages are already created without utilizing master pages. If you're just setting up your document, you should really make use of master pages in your workflow, as Marc Edwards pointed out.)

Here is a little snippet that could be used as a script in your specific situation. It checks for each element if it reaches below the lower page border and if that's the case it aligns this element with the lower page border.

```
#target InDesign

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var pageHeight = doc.documentPreferences.pageHeight;

for(var i = 0; i < doc.pageItems.length; i++){

    if(doc.pageItems[i].geometricBounds[2] > pageHeight){

        var offset = doc.pageItems[i].geometricBounds[2] - pageHeight;
        doc.pageItems[i].move(undefined, [0, -offset]);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice work! Gotta love scriptable apps.

Answer (score 2):

I assume all the pages have a similar layout? If so, I’d use a `master page` to ensure the layout is identical, and as you’d like.

It’s been a while since I’ve used InDesign, but these points from a Lynda article seem relevant:

#### Create a master from an existing page

> Have a document page you want to use as a master? No problem! Just drag a document spread into the master pages area of the Pages panel to create a new master spread from the document spread.

#### Apply master to many pages

> To quickly apply a master page to a range of document pages, target the document pages by shift-clicking on them, and then Option/Alt-click on the master.

All going well, you’ll be able to edit the master to make the change you’re after (and many subsequent changes will be easy).

More info here:
http://www.lynda.com/articles/indesign-master-pages-long-documents

Answer (score 0):

2023here. My reputation is not enough to like the answer but mdomino saved my life.
I don't know enough JS but I tried to add a little bit so it works also for the items which has higher bottoms than the page(forgive my stupid English)

#target InDesign

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var pageHeight = doc.documentPreferences.pageHeight;

for(var i = 0; i < doc.pageItems.length; i++){

```
if(doc.pageItems[i].geometricBounds[2] > pageHeight){

    var offset = doc.pageItems[i].geometricBounds[2] - pageHeight;
    doc.pageItems[i].move(undefined, [0, -offset]);
    }
if(doc.pageItems[i].geometricBounds[2] < pageHeight){

    var offset = doc.pageItems[i].geometricBounds[2] - pageHeight;
    doc.pageItems[i].move(undefined, [0, -offset]);
    }
}
```